# Why spread operator is missing out data?

Tags: javascript, rest, promise, javascript-objects, octokit-js

I am working with Github API using Octokit library.

I have a function which list out all the repository of a user(username). I have called this function on click of a button called `Fetch`

For sake of simplicity, I am rendering out only 1st repository(using index 0).

```
const list = []

  function fetchRepos() {
    octokit.repos
      .listForUser({
        username: 'abhinav-anshul',
      })
      .then((details) => list.push(details.data[0].name))

    console.log('List Array', list)

    const list2 = [...list]
    console.log(list2)
  }
```

As we can see in the code, I am handling a promise chain, and in that promise chain, I am pushing the repo result in the empty array called list.

In the `console.log('List Array', list)`, I am able to get the '0th' repo name correctly, as given in the image below:

[image]

But when I try to use `spread operator` to pass the list array to a new array called `list2` and do a `console.log(list2)` I get the following :

[image]

Why I have lost the name of the repo here? Am I doing something conceptually wrong?
Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `then()` is asynchronous, so it runs after your `console.log(list2)`. That's why your `list2` is still an empty array.

I suggest making your function `async`:

```js
const list = [];

async function fetchRepos() {
    const details = await octokit.repos
        .listForUser({
            username: 'abhinav-anshul',
        });

    list.push(details.data[0].name);

    console.log('List Array', list);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, for example the spreading operation `list2 = [...list]` should be included inside the callback you passed to `.then()`, so as to be sure it gets executed in time

Comment: @Luc125 or, even better, wrapping this functionality in `async` / `await` will make it readable.

Comment: Even I do it synchronously, It still returns a promise. How can I handle data further without promise?

Comment: This library works asynchronously, you don't have control over doing it synchronously. The only thing you can do is either use `then()` properly or marking your function as `async function` and putting `await` before calling an asynchronous methods.

Comment: @RoboRobok could you write a code snippet using async/await?

Comment: @RoboRobok Even I use async function, it is still an asynchronous task, so how will it solve the problem?

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul yes, please take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul `await` makes you write synchronous-like code for asynchronous operations. It just makes the following like wait until the `await`-ed operation is done. It can take anything between 0ms and forever, in theory.

Comment: @RoboRobok It is generating a new kind of side-effect

Comment: What do you mean?